# Component props not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm having a component in React. It's prop `group` should update when the state `cloneMode` change. For this I'm using the following code: 
Structure:

```
const DraggableElement = ({ list, setList, cloneMode }) => {
 return (
    <ReactSortable
      group={
        cloneMode
          ? { name: "tasks_group", pull: "clone" }
          : "tasks_group"
      }
      key={cloneMode}
      list={list}
      setList={setList}
      animation={200}
      delay={1}
      className="task-child_drag"
    >
      {list.map((e) => {
        return <TaskItem key={e._id} task={e} />;
      })}
    </ReactSortable>
  );
};
```

Parent:

```
const Tasks = () => {
  const [cloneMode, setCloneMode] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="tasks">
            <DraggableElement
              list={todo}
              setList={setTodo}
              cloneMode={cloneMode}
            />
            <DraggableElement
              list={inProgress}
              setList={setInProgress}
              cloneMode={cloneMode}
            />
            <DraggableElement
              list={done}
              setList={setDone}
              cloneMode={cloneMode}
            />
          </div>
  );
};
```

When I run `setCloneMode(true)`, it's not affecting the component. Any thoughts on how can I achieve it?

Comment: `cloneMode` is a prop in `DraggableElement`, where are you using the `useState`? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @Adam Sorry for the confusion! I've updated the question to include the parent component

Comment: And how/where do you call `setCloneMode(true)`?

Comment: That I did for testing in the Parent component. I did a `setTimeout` and `setCloneMode(true)`

Comment: @AjitKumar Can you try adding `key={cloneMode}` to the `ReactSortable` component

Comment: That should technically rerender when your state changes; You can verify that by adding a simple `console.log('rerendering')` within your `DraggableElement`

Comment: @fatihsolhan @ale917k Thank! I added the `key={cloneMode}` to the `ReactSortable` component That worked fine.. The component is now receiving the latest state and rerendering .. But, as in the question, the props are not updating, even when the state changes! I've updated the question

Comment: can you test that setting `"tasks_group"` and `{ name: "tasks_group", pull: "clone" }` is working fine without cloneMode ? can you test your `ReactSortable` that works properly with changing the group props manually?

Comment: and what is the `ReactSortable` ? tell me about the package name you usued

Comment: @nima I tested and it is working without cloneMode.

Comment: @nima I'm using react-sortablejs
https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs

Comment: I mean it's working fine with  `group={{ name: "tasks_group", pull: "clone" }}` and `group={"tasks_group"}` if you hard code them?

Comment: @AjitKumar Provide the part you change the state. (button or other element that deals with user interaction)

Comment: @nima Yes! When I hard code them, it's working perfectly.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV That I did for testing in the Parent component. I did a `setTimeout` and `setCloneMode(true)`

Comment: can you create a codesanbdox?

Comment: @AjitKumar Let me know if you are doing `setTimeout` this way(with no arrow function): `setTimeout(function () {
    setCloneMode(true);
})`

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV No. I'm doing it like this:
`setTimeout(() => {
 setCloneMode(true);
}, 2000)`

Comment: @AjitKumar did you try adding keys to each draggable element as well?

Comment: Why ReactSortable has key set like that `key={cloneMode}`?

Comment: @IgorOkorokov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69767852/component-props-not-updating-on-state-change#comment123355632_69767852

Comment: try to do something like setCloneMode(() => true)

Comment: Can you create a codsandbox link, here given code snippet props are not changes as you mentioned setCloneMode are changing . But where it is called ?

Comment: install the React Dev Tools to debug your problem properly. you can confirm the state/prop is updating or not easily.

Answer (score 0):

Without a codepen, any info about why you think the state isn't updating, or any more context it's difficult to answer your question but here is a list of things to try:

1. Open up [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and confirm the state/prop is/isn't updating. Alternatively, you can check by having prop become the value of a data attribute so you can see it in the inspector `data-test={cloneMode}`.
2. Remove the `key` prop from your `DraggableElement` component. You don't need a key here. If you're going to use a key anywhere in React it should be unique. The way you have this setup now all the keys will be either true or false.
3. If all else fails I'd try manually passing in a `true` prop value for one of these to make 100% sure that the prop isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, You're not changing the state (or forgot to write it down). Without it we can't answer your question.

This is the default behavior of React. `Component should rerender once the value of props or state is changed`.

So, download [React Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) which is a browser extension for Chrome or Edge which helps to see/change the value of props and state from chrome developer window in real time. With this you'll get a better understanding of your Problem, and start to debug from there.